# Set "Quick Access" as default save location in MS Office

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, windows-10-quick-access

I would like to set my "Quick Access" from the File Explorer as my "Default local file location" under "Save" options in MS Office. However, when I try to do so I get a warning popup that reads

> Quick access:
>
> The folder name is not valid

[image]

Really, what I'd like is for the "Quick Access" option to be selected in my save window instead of "Computer."

As of a year ago, [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/quick-access-as-default-when-saving-a-word/2a3bcd5e-096a-4f40-bebb-1ff7d6a82ada) seems to suggest this is not possible...

> In line with your concern, you can only use the folders under Quick access as the default folder when saving a Word document and not the feature itself.

...but I was hoping progress has been made since then.

Anyone know how to go about doing this (directly or creatively)?

---

<sup>Specs: Windows 10, MS Office 2016</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it. To save a a file, you need a valid file system location. Quick Access is a virtual folder with no corresponding file system folder. It's nothing but a collection of shortcuts generated on the fly --- it all disappears when you power down.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Keith Miller, Quick Access is not a real file location so you can't set it as default save location.  But you can set a folder show up in Quick Access. Please refer to [Pin, remove, and customize in Quick access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/4027032/windows-pin-remove-and-customize-in-quick-access)

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder e.g. Quicks, that contains only shortcuts to your favorite folders and file locations. Set your default save location to "Quicks". Then you can blaze to your preferred save locations.